# Excel - VBA won't copy time when it's set to 00:00:00

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a simple VBA macro to copy values from a sheet to another.
It works almost perfectly except when it comes to copy the time cell:

I have a value in sheet A (cell CL) : 09/11/2016  00:00:00 (french format, not the problem)

I try to copy this value to sheet B (cell G) with the following code :

```
Worksheets("MEP").Range("G" & activeRow).Value = Replace(Worksheets("Export").Cells(rw.Row, "CL").Value, "#", Chr(10))
```

(ignore the replace function)

The result is : 09/11/2016
Without the time...

How can I force Excel to include the time ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the destination cell formatted the same as the source cell?

Comment: I don't want it to be hardcoded. Ended up by copying the cell and then PasteSpecial with values only. Works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This to copy from sheet2 to sheet1 the specific cell, including format:

```
Sheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 3).copy Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
```

Comment: Was currently trying that. Works perfect but a small problem remains, how not to apply the style of the source cell ?

Comment: to just keep the format copy the cell value and then as @bzimor says:
` Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss" `

Answer (score 0):

After changing, set this number format:

```
Worksheets("MEP").Range("G:G").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss"
```